# Copying a cell from a selected range of columns to a specific column while keeping the same row

Tags: vba, copy

I've been trying to organise my data that all of the similar data (found in several column) can be copied to a single column. Here is simplified version of the script I wrote so far (the range includes more column, but I reduced it for visual reasons here). I'm not sure how to tell that I want that i want to copy in this the row where the selected cell is. I hope I'm being clear enough.

```
Dim value As String
Dim rngTemp1 As Range
Dim rngTemp2 As Range
Dim rngTemp3 As Range
Dim rngTemp4 As Range
Dim rngTemp5 As Range

With Workbooks("ExploringTheRelation.xlsx").Sheets("ExploringTheRelation")
Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngTemp1 = .Range("W2:W" & Lastrow & ", AB2:AB" & Lastrow)
Set rngTemp2 = .Range("X2:X" & Lastrow & ", AC2:AC" & Lastrow)


For Each cell In rngTemp1
cell.Copy
cell(18, **Row**).Paste
Next cell

For Each cell In rngTemp2
cell.Copy
cell(18, **Row**).Paste
Next cell

End With
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you're trying to consolidate data across columns into one column? If so, adjust this as needed:

```
Dim rowStart    as long
Dim cell        as variant
Dim rngTemp1    as excel.range

rowStart = 2
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In rngTemp1
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            .Cells(rowStart, 6).Value = cell.Value
            rowStart = rowStart + 1
        End if
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: ya beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful. and worked perfectly. However, I just realized that (i should have though about it before) some of the cells in the destination column already had value. Therefore, it copied a blank cell. I will then either insert a column or put the consolidated column at the end. Or is there a way to prevent the copy if the cell is not empty?

Comment: I might have been too quick to say it works. While technically what I asked for definitely works, it seems like it only take the first column in the range In this *Set rngTemp1 = .Range("W2:W" & Lastrow & ", AB2:AB" & Lastrow)* , only the column W will be copied, not the following ones

Comment: I'm guessing you want the range to be: `.Range("W2:AB" & Lastrow)`
(I also updated my answer to ignore blanks)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Just adding in another variable to count the previous row that a value was added into.

```
With Workbooks("ExploringTheRelation.xlsx").Sheets("ExploringTheRelation")

    'finds the bottom row of data
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    Dim rngTemp1 As Range
    Set rngTemp1 = .Range("W2:W" & lastRow & ", AB2:AB" & lastRow)

    Dim rngTemp2 As Range
    Set rngTemp2 = .Range("X2:X" & lastRow & ", AC2:AC" & lastRow)

    'keeps track of the last row that a value was put into
    Dim currRow As Long
    currRow = 1

    'loops through a range and puts each value into column "R" one after another
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rngTemp1
        .Cells(currRow, "R").Value2 = cel.Value2
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Next cell

    For Each cel In rngTemp2
        .Cells(currRow, "R").Value2 = cel.Value2
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Next cell

End With
```

Comment: THanks for the reply, very similar to the post before and it worked like charm

Comment: @Cunneryn Definitely a 'great minds think alike' situation ;)